# Heartbeat engine in spring websocket, how to set?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have an android client and server(and websocket stomp configured), configured like the following:

```
    @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
            .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] {10000, 10000})
            .setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/api");
}
```

so every period of time heartbeat is sent by the server.

Should the client respond somehow ?

PS STOMP is used